# Getting data from mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have three tables `users(id, login), groups(id, name), users_groups(user_id, group_id)`. User can be in few groups simultaneously. How I can get `group names` for specific `user's id` in one statement?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`SELECT groups.name 
FROM groups 
WHERE groups.id in (
    SELECT rel.group_id 
    FROM users_groups rel 
    WHERE rel.user_id = 'your_user_id'
);`